# Rewriting a URL

Tags: .htaccess, seo, friendly-url, dynamic-pages

I developed my website so that all pages are loaded dynamically on 1 page by ajax, and so that the URL will appear in this format:

```
www.website.com/#home
www.website.com/#news
www.website.com/#news-details/news-title-goes-here
```

I discovered later-on that my pages aren't appearing in search engines and Google bots won't visit me this way.
So what's the easiest way to fix it and convert URL into this form:

www.website.com/news/news-title-goes-here

Could it be done with just modifying .htaccess ?

Comment: If the pages are loaded dynamically, is the content on the page also generated dynamically?

Comment: yes, everything is brought from the database

Comment: Have you tried submitting a site map in google webmaster tools?
http://www.feedthebot.com/dynamicpages.html

Comment: Tried it, and didn't work. and I tried using fetch as Google from the webmaster, it only fetches the home page

Comment: I will suggest you to create a SiteMap for your dynamic URLs!

Comment: Was the sitemap dynamic too?  I once created a static sitemap that contained all the dynamic urls, that helped Google find the pages on my site.

Comment: I created the sitemap manually (link by link) at first, just in order to fix this and it didn't work. The weird thing is that the text in my sitemap is appearing in Google search under www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml  but the link itself isn't appearing in Google results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this link:

```
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/
```

Converted all my dynamic pages to appear in this way:

```
www.website.com/#!home
www.website.com/#!news
www.website.com/#!news-details/news-title-goes-here
```

**(added the ! after the Hash)**

Then generated Html snapshots dynamicly. (however I made them in only 1 file html-snapshot.php)
So now I had 2 types of URL:

the Ugly one:

```
www.website.com/html-snapshot.php?_escaped_fragment_=news-details/news-title-goes-here
```

and the pretty one:

```
www.website.com/#!news-details/news-title-goes-here
```

I added all the pretty URLs into a sitemap and submitted in Google Webmaster, and Fetched all the Ugly ones in the webmaster tools "Fetch as Google"

and in summary that's it, Google is now seeing all my ajax pages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Google is getting confused.  You may have inadvertently stumbled into a cloaking situation.

If you look at other sites that have dynamic content loading on a homepage (like a news site), that content is eventually linked back to another content page (with it's own URL).  When you introduce pound/hash signs into your URL, Google is seeing that as an anchor point on the same page it was on before (this is the traditionally accepted use of hash in a URL), and expects to see all of the same content.  If you're keying on this hash and loading completely new content it's causing Google to be confused.

If Google is hitting the same URL and getting different content from AJAX calls, and it can't figure out that the different content is actually coming from different "pages" then Google could interpret this as cloaking, and drop your pages from the index.

Here's another thing you can try; hashbang URLs: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: Have you tried prayer?

Seriously, I think you're in a tough spot with no easy way out.  You could try to maybe key on a different character other than the hash sign, since that's already established. It may work, but it may not.

I've been doing SEO/Online marketing with Google for 10 - 15 years, worked SEO on hundreds of sites of all sizes.  One thing I've learned time and time again.  What's good for design/UX/looks pretty, often doesn't play nice with SEO and search engines in general.  Besides, even if Google can figure it out, Bing/Yahoo aren't as smart & they drive 20 - 30% of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty basic SEO vs coolnes problem.
If you like to keep the way your page is behaving, you could add a static version in parallel.

The following code in your htacess routes any request back to your index.php where you can select output the content based on those values.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

I'm writing this with my phone while sitting in the train (bored) so please excuse if the formatting isn't perfect ;)

Edit:
I nearly forgot; you get the url like this when using this method:
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];